# WPF vb.net Download Button without interruptions

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, button

I have pageA which has 2 buttons(button1 &button2) that navigate via frame1 to pageB(via button1) & pageC(via button2) (respectfully). On pageC( via button2) I have a download button that downloads from remote source.

What is the best practice/way to make sure that when downloadbutton is clicked and downloading (in PageC), that it doesn't get interrupted if button1 on pageA is clicked (maybe a message warning or disable button ?).

Does this make sense? Any help would be great!

Comment: d/load in the background ...

Comment: If you're on page C to click the download button, how can a button on page A be clicked? Page A isn't visible anymore, right? If you have returned to page A, why do you think that the download would stop if you click another button?

Answer (score 0):

This is why I am a newbie!
The answer is to use NavigationService
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1